# Declaring type of an object inside a function call?

Tags: typescript, typechecking

In TypeScript, I can do this:

```
function someFunction(options:any) {
    // Do something
}

interface MyOptions {
    userId: number;
    verbose: boolean;
}

const options: MyOptions = {
    userId: 12345,
    doesntExist: false, // Error
}

someFunction(options);
```

And that will give me a compilation error on the "doesntExist" property.

The problem is when I do the same thing without creating an intermediate variable:

```
someFunction({
    userId: 12345,
    doesntExist: false, // no error
});
```

In that case, since `someFunction` accepts `any` as a parameter, type checking is not enforced. Even if I do this, the compiler doesn't complain:

```
someFunction({
    userId: 12345,
    doesntExist: false, // no error
} as MyOptions);
```

So I'm wondering is there any way to enforce type checking without creating the intermediate variable?

Comment: Not if you have `any`... that type is *explicitly* an escape from the type check mechanism. Also, not that [the excess property check](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) are only done on direct assignment, so if you do `options: MyOptions = anotherObject` you will **not** get an error for extra properties.

Comment: The type error you get is because you typed `options` and then set it with a value that does not match its type. The function `someFunction` will never give you any type error since you put `any` (which is by the way not recommended).

Comment: Yes I understand this. What I was wondering is if there's a syntax that allows me to say "while the function takes 'any' as parameter, I declare that the object I'm passing is of type T". Perhaps it's not possible then and the extra variable is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I was wondering is if there's a syntax that allows me to say "while the function takes 'any' as parameter, I declare that the object I'm passing is of type T"

What you are describing is [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#hello-world-of-generics).

```
function someFunction<T>(options: T) {
  // Do something
}
```

If you just call the function without specifying the generic `T` then you won't get an error because typescript will assume that `T` is the type for whatever argument you provided.

But you can manually enter the generic as `MyOptions` and you will get an error when your argument isn't right.

```
someFunction<MyOptions>({
  userId: 12345,
  doesntExist: false // error
})
```

Here we get the error *Argument of type '{ userId: number; doesntExist: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MyOptions'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'doesntExist' does not exist in type 'MyOptions'.*

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/1WGx0w)